# I don't understand why the full string variable is not showing the response message it should

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So, I started learning something about python sockets module. I created two python files, the first one being the server.py (PC), and looks something like this:

```
from socket import *
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind(('my_IP_Address', 50003))
sockobj.listen(5)
while True:
    connection, address = sockobj.accept()
    connection.send(b'Welcome to the server')
    connection.close()
```

And another one which is client.py (Phone), the code looks the following:

```
from socket import *
socketobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socketobj.connect(('my_IP_Address', 50003))
full = ''
while True == True:
    mes = socketobj.recv(8)
    full += mes.decode()
print(full)
```

So, my question is, what should I do to get the connection.close() to work? I tried putting the print(full) inside of the while loop, and it would keep the message Welcome to the server repeated. I assume this is because the full has the value of 'Welcome to the server', but then once I call it outside of the while, it prints out nothing. I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but I just picked up on the sockets module and need help from the professionals. The reason the stream is set to 8, is because I want to concatenate the bits of the messages received into one full. Thanks

Comment: Be careful,  `import *` is generally bad practice, and `while True == True` is illogical!

Comment: I understand the concern about True == True, however, if I just create an infinite loop with while True: the 'code bellow' or print(full) simply becomes unreachable.

Comment: _if I just create an infinite loop with while True: the 'code bellow' or print(full) simply becomes unreachable._ That's extremely strange it shouldn't make a difference. You're missing the `:`, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote the code didn't copy/paste it, however the result is still the same, it says 'This code is unreachable', I could send you a picture if it would help you. Also, when I just put import socket and run the server script, the terminal opens and immediately closes, but when I put from socket import * it works somehow.

Comment: No matter what you with loop condition, as long as it is an infinite loop the `print(full)` will never be executed. That's what *inifinite loop* means. Your client needs to read from the socket until `socketobj.recv(8)` returns a value that indicates there is no more data left. Then you can close the socket, print the message, and exit the loop.

Comment: You need to handle (i.e. break on) the end of stream condition instead of looping forever. Don't ask me how that is manifested in Python, but it is.

Comment: End of stream is indicated when `recv()` returns the empty bytes object, `b""`.

Comment: Thank you James Reinstate Monica Polk, a simple if comparison did the trick!